# How to convert hex data to decimal degree latitude and longitude?

Tags: gps

I have been trying to decode GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) which is in HEX format, and the documentation doesn't have a clear explanation, please help me out. I'm adding some examples below.

latitude    0x414F51 = +28.758963 dd(decimal degree)

longitude   0x45429B = +077.627784dd(decimal degree)

[screenshot of the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjq0H.png)

[official documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyrjN76F-_us1IhmssmuZg-9ufj-GmUV/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

your screenshot probably contains example data and not real values

first of all both longitude and latitude are 4 bytes as per your documentation

and there is an example of normal packet in your documentation

based on that packets data lat and long are as follows

```
4E    41 4F 51 53  N   AOQS   

45    42 9B 7D 5C  E   B›}\
```

these are normal [IEEE float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

```
:\>xxd -s 94  -l 1 foo.bin
000005e: 4e                                       N

:\>xxd -s 95  -l 4 foo.bin
000005f: 414f 5153                                AOQS

:\>xxd -s 99  -l 1 foo.bin
0000063: 45                                       E

:\>xxd -s 100  -l 4 foo.bin
0000064: 429b 7d5c                                B.}\

:\>cdb -c ".formats 414f5153;q" cdb | grep -i float
  Float:   low 12.9574 high 0

:\>cdb -c ".formats 429b7d5c;q" cdb | grep -i float
  Float:   low 77.7448 high 0

:\>
```

reverse geocoding this location is as shown in screen shot

[image]

Comment: Here is hex to floating point converter, https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/

Comment: what for ? there are infinite such convertors floating around   in fact i have written such a convertor as a windbg extension  googit  f2h